# Jekyll - show images & text in slider

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid, static-site

I am using Bootstrap-Carousel.

Unfortunately, the data from `front-matter` is not being rendered.

index.html:

```
...
carousel:
  a:
    image: home/athenaBeta.jpeg 
    text: random text 1
  b: 
    image: home/transport.jpeg
    text: |
      random text 2
  c:
    image: home/coffee.jpeg 
    text: |
      random text 3
---
{% include hero-carousel.html %}
...
```

hero-carousel.html:

```
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" pause="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
      {% for news in page.carousel %}
      {% capture image %}
        {% assign img = news.image %}
      {% endcapture %}
      <div class="item img-cover img-fixed {% if forloop.index == 0 %}active{% endif %}" style="background-image:url({{ image }})">
        <h2>{{ news.text }}</h2>
      </div>
      {% capture i %}{{ i | plus:1 }}{% endcapture %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="fa glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="fa glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="arrow-down" href="#content">
      <span class="fa glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

It renders the three slides, however, none of the images or text is rendered. The output I get in browser is as below:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" pause="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
    <div class="item img-cover img-fixed " style="background-image:url(

      )">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item img-cover img-fixed " style="background-image:url(

      )">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item img-cover img-fixed " style="background-image:url()">
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="fa glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="fa glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="arrow-down" href="#content">
    <span class="fa glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop in `page.caroussel`, you receive things like :

```
{{ news | inspect }}
==> ["a", {"image"=>"home/athenaBeta.jpeg", "text"=>"random text 1"}]
```

which is an array containing two elements.

In order to reach your image, you can do `{% assign img = news[1].image %}`, but you'd better refactor a little :

```
...
carousel:
  - image: home/athenaBeta.jpeg
    text: random text 1

  - image: home/transport.jpeg
    text: |
      random text 2

  - image: home/coffee.jpeg
    text: |
      random text 3
---

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" pause="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
  {% for news in page.carousel %}
    <div class="item img-cover img-fixed {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" style="background-image:url('{{ news.image }}')">
      <h2>{{ news.text }}</h2>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation to convert the text to array. The text is displaying now, however, the image isn't. I get error `could not find the asset ''`.

Comment: I guess, Im not clear on how path to images / assets work in jekyll.

Comment: Thank you again, the syntax that worked for me is: `<div class="item img-cover img-fixed {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" style="background-image: url({% pic '{{ news.image }}' %})">` Im not sure where `pic` variable is coming from & why `'` around the object. Im amending someone else's website.

Comment: `{% pic ...` is a custom tag. It can be interesting to know from wish plugin it comes from.

Comment: yes you are right, I guessed its being inherited from some ancestor. Thanks for your help.